# How, with Python, can i retrieve the data content of a POST request?

Tags: python, django, woocommerce

I have a WooCommerce webhook who sends a POST request to a specific URL (http://po.tic.ch/polls/hello) for every order on my website. This WooCommerce is running on https://vi.tic.ch.

For each order, i want to retrieve the informations of the POST like *user ID = 12*, *product ID = 234*, *price = 50CHF*, etc. to save it in my server po.tic.ch.

The server po.tic.ch runs Django with Apache2. He have the port 80 open and receives all the POSTS but i don't know how to get the his content.

I tried this on my views.py file:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
import json


@csrf_exempt
def hello(request):
   # r = json.loads(request.POST)
    r = json.loads(request.POST.body)
    print(r)
    return HttpResponse(r)



def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return HttpResponse('This is GET request')

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return HttpResponse('This is POST request')
```

[the POST request on my Django](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XoGgS.png)

Thank You!

Comment: What is "your test.py file"? Is it part of your Django app? How is it called? You need to provide actual details if you want help. Also, you should read the Django documentation which is perfectly detailed.

Comment: Also note, you have at least two syntax errors in that code, which is pretty impressive given there are only two lines of code.

Comment: `def application(environ,start_response):
    status = '200 OK'
    html = '<html>\n' \
           '<body>\n' \
           '<div style="width: 100%; font-size: 40px; font-weight: bold; text-align: center;">\n' \
           'mod_wsgi Test Page\n' \
           '</div>\n' \
           '</body>\n' \
           '</html>\n'
    response_header = [('Content-type','text/html')]
    start_response(status,response_header)
    return [html]`

Comment: it's a simple web page

Comment: I don't know if I need to use some Django Events who reacts at the POST request

Comment: That doesn't answer any of my questions. What is that file? Why is it separate from the Django app? Why don't you write this as a Django view? Have you actually read any of the Django documentation?

Comment: The code you've posted as a comment is illegible. Please edit it into your question. Also, at a guess, you want `r = requests.POST.get('id')`

Comment: okay, i use now the Django base web server

Comment: i tried the r = requests.POST.get('id') but it does'nt react to the POSTs requests

Comment: @AlexTravasso What do you mean it "doesn't react to"? Have you set up urls so that a POST request is actually triggering some function in views? I'm also not sure why you have `self` in your views.py functions.

Comment: @roganjosh no, i only have one url defined  `url(r'^hello/$', views.hello, name='hello')`

Comment: If `request.POST.get('id')` doesn't give what you expect, then check what `request.POST` actually is.

Answer (score 1):

that's what i was searching.... thanks anyway

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
import json


@csrf_exempt
def hello(request):
    r = json.loads(request.body)
    mail = (r['billing']['email'])
    print (mail)
    return HttpResponse(r)
```

Answer (score -1):

If your function receives all `POST` request, you can simply access the body via `data = request.get('data', None)`. This will return the request data or `None` in case of an empty request.